# Gettig OrientDB Java heap

Tags: java, exception, heap-memory, orientdb, depth

I'm running this query to traverse a graph

**Query :**

```
TRAVERSE out("Re") FROM #21:39161 WHILE $depth <= 3 
          STRATEGY BREADTH_FIRST
```

**My dataset is 11M edges and 20000 nodes** .

I'm getting this java exception

```
 [OServer]java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
Dumping heap to java_pid3920.hprof ...
Heap dump file created [911684234 bytes in 26,730 secs]
```

I'm using this configuration

```
rem ORIENTDB MAXIMUM HEAP. USE SYNTAX -Xmx<memory>, WHERE <memory> HAS THE TOTAL MEMORY AND SIZE UNIT. EXAMPLE: -Xmx512m
set MAXHEAP=-Xmx6G 
rem ORIENTDB MAXIMUM DISKCACHE IN MB, EXAMPLE: "-Dstorage.diskCache.bufferSize=8192" FOR 8GB of DISKCACHE
set MAXDISKCACHE=8GB
```

How Can i fix this?

Comment: You have to increase the max heap value of your java process.

Comment: @pabrantes I increased the max value to 10G per 4G for disk still getting GC exeeded

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
TRAVERSE out("Re") FROM #21:39161 MAXDEPTH 3 STRATEGY BREADTH_FIRST
```

MAXDEPTH is more efficient in terms of RAM and speed. If doesn't work, reduce the DISKCACHE and put the cut into the heap. So:

```
set MAXHEAP=-Xmx10G 
set MAXDISKCACHE=4GB
```

Comment: When doing that already reached 13G for 1G for disk , now I'm getting GC exeeded